# How to give a polkadot referendum Track the authority to mint an Asset on asset hub?

Tags: polkadot, assets, pallet-asset

The goal is to give a polkadot referendum Track the authority to mint an Asset on asset hub.

We want to avoid Root referendum because that requires `100,000 DOT` decision deposit.

We would like to through one of the other referendum tracks.

The hypothesis is:

- The referendum track (like Medium Spender) can act as an Origin.
- We can assign Medium Spender to be the `Issuer` of an asset on AssetHub.
- A referendum can be passed which contains an xcm instruction to mint tokens on asset hub.

I will try and test this and share an answer as well, but any support would be appreciated. Perhaps i am missing a step, or perhaps there is a better way to achieve the stated goal.